# How to write a query to select data with a date format 'DD-MMM-YYYY'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query in `SELECT` statement with the format `'DD-MMM-YYYY'` eg:

`'1-Jan-2019'` or `'23-Mar-2018'`

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate(), 106)`?

Comment: [The fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) has this covered.

Comment: @Sami: if you want `VARCHAR(30)`, write that. Otherwise, better [be explicit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Do you mean the table data field is in that format, or the input parameter/query clause date is in that format? (I assume you are comparing a field to a value but you didn't actually say what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Personally, I would return the date as a `date` in your SQL and have your presentation layer do the formatting.

Comment: Starting with SQL-Server there is [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This function is not known to be fast, but it is very flexible. In general it is very dangerous to rely on system and language dependant formats. In your data layer this should be a simple `DATE`, while your presentation layer handles the human readable output...

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate(), 106)
```

**Returns:**

```
23 Jan 2019
```

See **[`CAST and CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles)** where the **[`Date and Time Styles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles)**

If you really want to return `'-'` separator, you can do as

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate(), 106), ' ', '-')
```

**Returns:**

```
23-Jan-2019
```

Comment: Worth noting that the results depend on the language setting. This will return `23-janv-201` if the language is French.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage T-SQL FORMAT() to request exact format of the output and culture as you require:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), '%d-MMM-yyyy', 'en')
```

It is available since SQL Server 2012

However, better practice is to control format on an app level

Comment: only problem here is if day is between 1 and 9, then will have leading zero, so not exactly as OP asked

Comment: @PawelCzapski, thanks, you are right, the format statement adjusted to %d, so it will return day without leading zero

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the dashes e.g. '1 jan 2018' then that works out of the box. It is also a really nifty format that always works if you don't know the database settings.

Just remember that month names are abbriviated differently for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that pretty easily with a Convert call in SQL to a numbered format. It will be close to what you want, but for your format exactly you will need to replace the spaces in the string with dashses by using a Replace call on the result of the convert.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Example:

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GetDate(), 106), ' ', '-')
```